# How to write a custom TimeseriesGenerator for processing a batch of input files containing timeseries data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I am trying to write a custom TimeseriesGenerator in Python to batch process some files that contain timeseries data. The files are organized as:

data/

- train/

  - train_data_00
  - train_data_01
  - ..
  - train_data_34
- validation/

  - val_data_00
  - ..
  - val_data_08
- test/

  - test_data_00
  - ..
  - test_data_08

Each of the files contains timeseries data, obtained from an inertial measurement unit, and a label for the type of activity that was performed at that time instance. Hence, the data within the individual files are organized with the columns representing:
acc_X, acc_Y, acc_Z, gyro_X, gyro_Y, gyro_Z, label

Now, what I want to develop is a model to predict the type of activity (i.e. the label) for a given input timeseries. Therefore, I want to segment the timeseries data using a sliding window approach with a user-defined `WINDOW_LENGTH` and `WINDOW_STEP`

Ideally, I would want a function that is provided the path, e.g. `train_data_dir = "./data/train"`, and then generate batches of input data that can be used with `fit_generator` to train the model.

Right now, I loop over the files in a directory:

```py
# Load the data from a single file
with open(os.path.join(train_data_dir, fname), 'rb') as infile:
    X, y = cp.load(infile)

# Define window length, step size and batch size
win_len = 512
win_step= 128
batch_size = 64

# Instantiate TimeseriesGenerator object
timeseries_gen = MyTimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=win_len, stride=win_step, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, mode="last")
```

Here, the `TimeseriesGenerator` object is defined as:

```py
class MyTimeseriesGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, data, labels, length, stride=1, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, mode="last"):
        """
        Class constructor for the custom Timeseries Generator.
        
        Every `Sequence` must implement the `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods, 
        see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence
        
        The method `__getitem__` should return a complete batch.        
        """
        #self.data = np.asarray([data[n:n+length,:] for n in range(0, len(data)-length+1, stride)])
        #self.labels = np.asarray([labels[n+length-1] for n in range(0, len(labels)-length+1, stride)])
        self.labels = labels
        self.length = length
        self.stride = stride
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.mode = mode
        self.data, self.labels = self.get_data(data, labels)
            
    def __len__(self):
        """
        Number of batches in the Sequence.
        """
        return len(self.data) // self.batch_size
    
    def get_data(self, data, labels):
        """
        Get the data and labels.
        """
        # Read data into a numpy array with dimensions (n_windows, window_length, n_channels)
        X = np.asarray([data[n:n+self.length,:] for n in range(0, len(data)-self.length+1, self.stride)])
        
        # Read labels into a numpy array with dimensions (n_windows, n_outputs)
        if self.mode == "last":
            y = np.asarray([labels[n+self.length-1] for n in range(0, len(labels)-self.length+1, self.stride)])

        return X, y
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Gets batch at position `index`.
        """
        
        # Get next batch        
        batch_x = self.data[index*self.batch_size : (index+1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[index*self.batch_size : (index+1)*self.batch_size]
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

This work for this single file, but how would I adjust the code to generate batches of training/validation/testing for all files in the corresponding folders? I think I want something to call the generator as in:

```py
timeseries_gen = MyTimeseriesGenerator(path="train_data_dir", length=win_len, ...)
```

Ideally, I also want to have the option to shuffle the generate training samples (via the `shuffle` keyword and an `on_epoch_end()` method)

Note: a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898526/input-pipeline-for-lstm-with-timeseries-data-using-a-large-dataset-with-multiple), but there was no follow up on it.

EDIT: Or would it be a valid workaround to generate one large numpy array over, e.g., all training files, and supply this array to the timeseries generator?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, I have not yet found an appropriate solution, and am looking into the issue again.